# In SQLRPGLE we use Sqlcode. Where do we get this variable from?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

In SQLRPGLE we use Sqlcode. But we do not declare this variable in our program. So my query is where do we get this variable from? How come this variable is available to the program without declaring it?

Comment: you should probably take a read through the [Embedded SQL Programming](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=programming-embedded-sql) manual

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A SQLRPGLE needs to be pre-compiled with CRTSQLRPGI.
The precompiler adds this variable and others in your source, and then compiles the new source
[See CRTSQLRPGI](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/cl/crtsqlrpgi.htm)

Comment: Kunal, if you look in your compile listing, you can see all the definitions added by the SQL precompiler. The names of the added definitions all start with "SQL".